# Download new app from within an iPhone-app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, download, in-app-purchase, itunes-sdk

I have developed a game and are planning to make a "Lite" version of that game in order to promote the "Premium" version of the game. Information about how to make In-App-Purchase is easy to find. But what I cannot find is how to actually download the application from within my Lite-version, after the purchase. I do not intend to update the lite version to a preimum version but instead treat the premium version as a new application that must be downloaded.

How do I do that, and where can I find that information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concepts "in app purchase" and "new application" are mutually exclusive.

The easiest thing to do is just let people navigate to your new app on the itunes store, and let them decide whether or not to buy it from there:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.itunes.com/apps/yourPaidVersionAppName"]];
```

Comment: make sure the button that does this says "View full version on the app store" or similar rather than "Buy now". "Buy now" is scary and implies an immediate loss of funds.

Comment: can we return in our application after purchasing from itune store..?

Answer (score 2):

Calling the next line would do the magic:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://link_to_your_full_application_in_appstore"]];
```

You might use a button in your UI and once the user touches it to call the line from above (after filling the exact URL of our app - as mentioned in another answer it could be @"http://www.itunes.com/apps/your_app_name" or even better @"http://www.itunes.com/apps/your_name/your_app_name").

Comment: A little explanation for those who don't understand what you're trying to convey would be great.

Comment: can we return in our application after purchasing from itune store..?

Comment: @Rajneesh071, no, you can't return to the app. But since I have written this answer Apple has added a possibility to open the AppStore within your application (available since iOS6). So you might open a SKStoreProductViewController inside your app. This way you will return in the app...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot download new application within your app. I think all you can do with in-app purchase is

- enable some extra features
- let user download some extra contents

You can also provide a itunes link to your full version so you will be able to open the standard appstore application on your full version page and let user download it.

Comment: I found some info about what can be purchased with in-App-Purchase. I was hoping that I just didn't understand how to apply that info to what I wanted, but I understand now that it is not possible. I need to "just" market the application and link to it with the linke provided in the other comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you  can't. That wouldn't require in-app purchase, but another version of your app up on the AppStore. Which defeats the point of being able to use in-app purchase to upgrade an existing Lite version to the full-blown one.

Downloads of new content packs is achievable, but you will have to have your own hosting for that obviously.

Surely creating one version of your app is far easier? Crippled by default, and upgradeable through in-app purchase.

Comment: Wow, four answers in 20 minutes, this is a very responsive forum :) 

Thanks for the answers. In this case I want to the functionality to be sligthly different, that's why I want a new application. It's possible to enable the enhanced functionality in some way, for sure not the easiest way though. I will have to consider this solution though.