# Download .app from link

Tags: ios, safari, hyperlink, download

What kind of link do I need in order to download a .app file from Safari directly onto a device?

I want to do the same with .apk's, so any information / code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what device? Are you talking about downloading an app in an iPhone from iPhone's browser?

Comment: Yes. Or and app from an iPad's browser.

Comment: OK; possible duplicate of [Download new app from within an iPhone-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191223/download-new-app-from-within-an-iphone-app).

Answer (score 3):

You should use enterprise distribution.  When you create your application archive there will be an option to do enterprise distribution.  Once you do this you will get your archive as well as a .plist manifest file.  Using these you should be able to create a link by following these instructions:
https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/?lang=en-us#app43ad871e

You will still need to get your users' UDIDs and create a provisioning profile for them to use. (iTunes required once)

Once that's done your users can click a link and directly install the app.  (No itunes required!)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the current app store structure.  Unless you are doing some sort of in-house distribution using an Enterprise developer license then the only way to get an app is through an app store link.

If you are thinking about using some kind of limited ad-hoc distribution you will still need to use itunes or iPhoneConfigurator to install it.